# Required text, isn't showing up, no clues why?

Tags: php

So I got this small script -

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['description'] == '')
{
    echo '<strong><font color="Red" size="2">REQ!</font></strong>';
} 
else
{
    echo '';
}
```

But it is not showing up after submit button has been pressed and if description is empty. All of the input names are correct, any help would pe appreciated, cause I just somehow can't find answer to this easy question.
Best regards,
Valters

Comment: Have you tried doing `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Yeah it turns back - array(0) { } .
Best regards,
Valters

Comment: @user996060: So... an empty array would tell you that it's not posting anything, right? Perhaps your form is not set up correctly.

Comment: It's not going to help you solve this specific issue, but consider getting rid of the `else` block since it's basically doing nothing.

Comment: Added HTML, will owe you big thanks if you will help me, cause now i'm sitting in chair, and just can't find where's problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me...

Please verify that `$placeadd->translate('required')` actually returns a string value. If it doesn't, or returns an empty string, you won't see any result unless you view the source of the code.

Comment: translate('required') returns everything fine ;(! if i remove isset... it just shows up without pressing button next, but checks, jsut doesn't work ;(!!!

Comment: Whooray! Finally found the problem! It was inside my class file, header('location: ...php'); fault ;)! Thanks to all who tried to help me!

Comment: As long as you provided me to right point, that code is working, I will choose you as best answer. Thanks!